# How to group consecutive dates in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have an xml file (sample below) and I want to group this xml based on consecutive Time_Off_Date.

> ```
> <Root>
>   <Entry>
>     <Employee_ID>101</Employee_ID>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-01</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-02</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-04</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-05</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details> 
>   </Entry>
>   <Entry>
>     <Employee_ID>102</Employee_ID>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-10</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-13</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details>
>     <Time_Off_Details>
>       <Time_Off_Date>2017-12-14</Time_Off_Date>
>     </Time_Off_Details>
>   </Entry>
> </Root>
> ```

The final output should look like this (in CSV format).

> ```
> Employee ID   Time Off Start  Time Off End
> 101           12/1/2017       12/2/2017
> 101           12/4/2017       12/5/2017
> 102           12/10/2017      12/10/2017
> 102           12/13/2017      12/14/2017
> ```

Is there a way to achieve this using XSLT 2.0 and without using recursive functions??
I am new to XSLT so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use the exact same tag for the start and end dates? Why not have one `<Time_Off_Details>` and in there `<Start_Date>` and `<End_Date>`?! And of course your Employee 102 has an odd number of dates and we have to guess that the 10th is a duplicate...

Comment: If you just want to treat dates in odd positions as start dates and those in even positions as end dates, that's easy and doesn't really need grouping. But where you have three dates and decide arbitrarily that one of them is both a start and an end date, I don't know what logic you are applying.

Comment: Is the logic that the input XML only holds individual days off (so one day at a time), and you want to group these individual days where they happen to be consecutive?

Comment: @AlexisWilke This is how Workday (the system I am getting the xml data from) is creating the xml file. Would it be easier to if the xml file had different tags??

Answer (score 2):

If the logic is that the input XML only holds individual days off and you want to group these individual days where they happen to be consecutive, then you can use `xsl:for-each-group` to select the `Time_Off_Details` with the `group-starting-with` set to the elements where the `Time_Off_Date` is not consecutive with the previous element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="Entry">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Time_Off_Details" 
                        group-starting-with="*[not(xs:date(Time_Off_Date) = xs:date(preceding-sibling::*[1]/Time_Off_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))]">
        <xsl:value-of select="../Employee_ID" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Time_Off_Date" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/Time_Off_Date" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. This worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This can be nicely expressed in XQuery 3 using the tumbling window clause (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-tumbling-windows):

```
for $entry in Root/Entry
for tumbling window $date in $entry//Time_Off_Date/xs:date(.)
start $s when true()
end $e next $n when $n - $e gt xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
return string-join(($entry/Employee_ID, $date[1], $date[last()]), '&#9;')
```

http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e25

As XSLT 2 processors like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime also support XQuery this might be an alternative to using XSLT.

For XSLT you might need to explain why you don't want to use a recursive function.

Comment: Hi Martin, The product I am working on, they do not allow me to use recursive functions so I`ll have to find out alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be done in **XSLT 2.0** using `for-each-group`.

First you have to sort all `Time_Off_Date` elements by their full content.

Each group starts with a `Time_Off_Date` element, for which it does not
exist any other `Time_Off_Date` element with the content equal to the
previous date, compared to the current date.

To compute the previous date, as a string, the following sequence is needed:

- Take the current date.
- Subtract the period of 1 day.
- Format it as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Then, for each group you need:

- Read the date from the first group member.
- Read the date from the last group member.
- Print *Employee_ID* and both dates, formatted as you require.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:text>Employee ID,Time Off Start,Time Off End&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Entry/Time_Off_Details/Time_Off_Date"
        group-starting-with=".[not(//Entry/Time_Off_Details/Time_Off_Date[. =
          format-date(xs:date(current()) - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'),
          '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')])]">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="startDate" select="current-group()[1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lastDate" select="current-group()[last()]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../Employee_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date($startDate,'[M01]/[D1]/[Y0001]')"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date($lastDate,'[M01]/[D1]/[Y0001]')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution! Appreciate your help.